# How to grab the wind data in table from "www.windguru.cz"?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I want to get the wind data from this site "www.windguru.cz".

Form the Google Chrome's build-in tool, the XPath of the table is //*[@id="tabid_0_content_div"].

But the problem is when I parse this XPath through HtmlAgilityPack, the IDE through NullReferenceException again and again.

I have no idea to solve it.

Can anyone give some hints?

Thanks a million.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because you are getting exact what browser gets when requesting that url. Those tables are generating by Javascript dynamically. I believe what you can do here is using combination of WebBrowser control and HTMLAgilityPack. Just wait until the page is loaded, after that you can use HAP.